# Equation representing a pair of equal straight lines

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I'm sorry for a dumb problem in advance but the problem states

> There exist two ordered triplets $(a_1, b_1 ,c_1)$ and $(a_2 , b_2 , c_2)$ for $(a, b, c)$ for which the equation $4x^2 - 4xy + ay^2 + bx + cy + 1 = 0$ represents a pair of identical straight lines in $x-y$ plane. Find the value of $a_1+ b_1 +c_1 +a_2 + b_2 +c_2$

The first thing I tried was $h^2-4ab=0$ and by that, I got the value of $a=1$ but I cannot seem to move further and find values of $b$ and $c$

The author just simply writes

> By observation, directly equation must be
> $(4x^2-4xy+y^2)+2(2x-y)+1=0$ or $(4x^2-4xy+y^2)-2(2x-y)+1=0$ and gives the answer $2$

PS: it's a highschool level problem.

Comment: What is $h$? Where did you get that equation $h^2-4ab=0$ from?

Comment: @AlanAbraham I used the property that in the equation of pair of straight lines written as $ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$ where 


$h^2-ab > 0$ are two distinct real lines
$h^2-ab = 0$ are incident lines
$h^2-ab < 0$ are imaginary lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation of a pair of identical straight lines is
$$(ux+vy+w)^2=0$$
Where $u,v,w$ are constants. We can match coefficients to see
$$u^2=4$$
$$2uv=-4$$
$$w^2=1$$
WLOG say $u=2$. This gives $v=-1$. Now we can case on whether $w=1$ or $w=-1$. Expanding the squared trinomial in both cases should give us the values for $a,b,c$.

Instead of directly solving for $a,b,c$, we can get the sum indirectly. We know that the factored form looks like
$$(2x-y\pm 1)^2=0$$
Note that the LHS expands into
$$4x^2-4xy+ay^2+bx+cy+1$$
If we plug in $x=1,y=1$ into the expression we get $a+b+c+1$. If we plug in $x=1,y=1$ into our factored form we get
$$(1\pm 1)^2$$
Which has value $0$ or $4$. Hence, the total sum of all possible values is $(0-1)+(4-1)=\boxed{2}$.

Comment: I'm sorry but is there any specific reason why $u$ cannot be equal to $-2$?

Comment: the answers come out to be the same I realized it's basically taking a common $-1$ which comes out and makes no changes. Thanks!

Comment: Yep exactly @3.14